# How to display music player notification using support libs v25

Tags: android, android-notifications

I use the following code to display a custom notification, but it's not displaying. 
The following is taken from my service class. Playback is successful upon clicking on a song, everything works but the notification.

compile sdk version 25 -
min sdk 21 -
target sdk 25

```
private void updateNotification ( ) {

     //   try {

            // normal notif
            RemoteViews smallView = new RemoteViews ( getPackageName ( ), R.layout.notification );
            smallView.setTextViewText ( R.id.notification_song_name, currentSong.getTitle ( ) );
            smallView.setTextViewText ( R.id.notification_artist_name, currentSong.getArtist ( ) );
            // expanded notif
            RemoteViews expanedView = new RemoteViews ( getPackageName ( ), R.layout.notification_expanded );
            expanedView.setTextViewText ( R.id.notification_song_name, currentSong.getTitle ( ) );
            expanedView.setTextViewText ( R.id.notification_album_name, currentSong.getAlbum ( ) );
            expanedView.setTextViewText ( R.id.notification_artist_name, currentSong.getArtist ( ) );



            if ( PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED ) {
                smallView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_play_pause_button, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp ) ).getBitmap ( ) );
                expanedView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_play_pause_button, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp ) ).getBitmap ( ) );
            }

            else {
                smallView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_play_pause_button, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.ic_pause_black_24dp ) ).getBitmap ( ) );
                expanedView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_play_pause_button, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.ic_pause_black_24dp ) ).getBitmap ( ) );
            }

            if ( currentSong.getIsLiked ( this ) )
                expanedView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_favorite_button, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp ) ).getBitmap ( ) );

            else
                expanedView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_favorite_button, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp ) ).getBitmap ( ) );


            setListeners ( smallView );
            setListeners ( expanedView );


            Bitmap albumArt = AudioExtensionMethods.getBitMap ( getBaseContext ( ), currentSong.getAlbumArtLocation ( ) );
            if ( albumArt != null ) {
                smallView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_album_art, albumArt );
                expanedView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_album_art, albumArt );
            }

            else {
                smallView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_album_art, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.unkown_album_art ) ).getBitmap ( ) );
                expanedView.setImageViewBitmap ( R.id.notification_album_art, ( (BitmapDrawable) getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.mipmap.unkown_album_art ) ).getBitmap ( ) );
            }



            // create an ongoing notif
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder ( this )
                .setContent ( smallView )
                .setSmallIcon ( R.mipmap.launcher_icon )
                .setOngoing ( true );

            // makes the notif dismissable when playback is paused
            if ( PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED ) {
                builder.setOngoing ( false );
            }



            if ( currentVersionSupportBigNotification ) {
                builder.setCustomBigContentView ( expanedView );
            }

            Intent nIntent = new Intent ( this, MainActivity.class );
            nIntent.putExtra ( "notificationIntent", true );
            nIntent.addFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity ( this, 0, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
            builder.setContentIntent ( pendingIntent );

            // send the notification
            Notification build = builder.build ( );
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService ( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
            notificationManager.notify ( NOTIFICATION_ID, build );
     //   }

      //  catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
```

I have no idea what's going wrong in here. Any help would be appreciated.
P.S. I'm not willing to update my libraries because updating crashes the app and I can't go writing the whole codes from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. It's funny how I solved it. It turns out that notifications, along with widgets, DO NOT support themes or whatever you call it. I was using "attr/primaryColor" in the notification's layout, and changing these to normal color formats solved the issue.